# Using Facebook group membership as condition for Facebook login on external site?

Tags: facebook-login, facebook-oauth, facebook-group

I am a hobby web developer running a website for my local concert band. The website has a public part and an internal part. Currently the internal part of the website is protected by a common username/password. In addition to the website, we have a closed Facebook group for all our active members. It is the members in this group who should have access to the internal part of the website, and we regularly get new members and lose old ones (thus the wish for moving away from common username/password). I would like to switch to Facebook login for the website (for control over who gets access, plus people won't have to remember personal usernames/passwords), and I have two specific questions in this regard. Keep in mind that I am completely new to Facebook login, oauth etc.

1. Is it possible to use membership status in said Facebook group to decide who gets access to the (internal part of the) website? How would I go about doing this?
2. If not, is it possible to directly specify which Facebook users will have access to the (internal part of the) website? How?